# Calculate circular velocity by comparison

Tags: velocity, rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

So I have this problem where I have to calculate circular speed but I don't have the mass. I can only do this by comparison.

So a ball rotates at $2.4 \ ms^{-1}$  with a radius of $0.8$ m. How much would be the velocity if the radius was reduced to $0.48$ m?

How can I do this by only comparing?

I tried calculate Period by doing $\dfrac{2\pi v}{r} = 2.09$ for the first ball but can't pass this.

Comment: Does circular speed means angular velocity ?

Comment: Well I'm not  sure if it is that. Looking at the values I have being v1 = 2.4m/s and r1 = 0.8, and then r2 = 0.48, how much would be v2?

Comment: Hum so v = w.r, I calculate W for v1, and then do the same for v2 and replace w with the value I got from the previous right?

Comment: Yes , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548631/why-is-angular-velocity-the-same-for-all-points-on-a-spinning-disk-even-though/548640#548640 u can read this for further understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one has to assume that there is no torque on the ball about the point it's rotating. So, it is like a pirouette problem
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{\tau}=\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}=0&\Rightarrow \mathbf{L}\text{ is constant.}\\
\Rightarrow mv_1r_1&=mv_2r_2
\end{align*}