# Proof angular velocity is invariant to translation on rigid body

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

My understanding is for a rigid body the angular velocity between two points fixed on the body is the same for all points. In other words the angular velocity vector would be the same. I can't find a proof of this.

To be clear I'm talking translating the origin on the body, not relocating the secondary point you're computing the angular velocity of.

Comment: That the angular velocity is the same for every point in a rigid body might very well be the very *definition* of a rigid body. What is *your* definition of a rigid body?

Comment: So my definition of angular velocity is wrt a central point acting as the center of the body. The above claims you can take any two points on a rigid body and they will have the same angular velocity vector.

Comment: I'm asking you for your definition of a *rigid body*, not the angular velocity. What I'm saying is that, from my perspective, a rigid body is one for which *every point in the object rotates at the same angular velocity about its center of mass*.  That is whats a rigid body *means*, and so there's no proof for it.

Comment: A rigid body is defined as a body with some point taken as the origin and every point on the body maintains a fixed position with respect to that point/frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is angular velocity the same for all points on a spinning disk, even though they are at different radii from the center?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548631/)